# TCP server socket not listening by addrinfo method

Tags: c, sockets, server, tcp

So here is the code, code successfully compiles...

```
#include <stdio.h> // for printf
#include <linux/if_tun.h> //for IFF_TUN
#include <sys/socket.h> //socket, struct sockaddr_in
#include <fcntl.h> // for O_RDWR macros
#include <string.h> //for strcpy
#include <unistd.h> //for read();
#include <netdb.h> //for struct sockaddr
#include <net/if.h> //struct ifreq and IFNAMSIZ and other macros
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// _check: error handler
static int _check(int retval, const char *msg)
{
    if(retval == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", msg, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return retval;
}


int tcp_listen_sock(int listen_connection)
{
    /*-------------------------socket-----------------------*/
    int sock, tcp_sock;
    struct addrinfo hints, *result;
    struct sockaddr *addrin;

    memset(&hints ,0 , sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    const char *host;

    host = "0.0.0.0";

    _check(getaddrinfo(host, NULL, &hints, &result), "getaddrinfo");

    if (result->ai_family == AF_INET)
    ((struct sockaddr_in *)result->ai_addr)->sin_port = htons(5678);
  else if (result->ai_family == AF_INET6)
    ((struct sockaddr_in6 *)result->ai_addr)->sin6_port = htons(5678);
  else {
    fprintf(stderr, "unknown ai_family %d", result->ai_family);
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    return -1;
  }
    memcpy(addrin, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
//  *client_len = result->ai_addrlen;

    _check((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)), "socket");
    
    struct ifreq ifr;

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "enp0s3");
    _check(setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, (void *)&ifr, sizeof(ifr)), "setsockopt");

    int flags;
    if((flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL)) != -1)
    {
        fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    }
    else
    perror("socket fcntl");

            _check(bind(sock,result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen), "tcp bind");


    int len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    _check(listen(sock, listen_connection), "listen");
    tcp_sock = accept(sock, result->ai_addr, &result->ai_addrlen );
    
    printf("now listening on tcp!\n");
    
    return tcp_sock;
    
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Starting program\n");
    int tcp = tcp_listen_sock(5);
   printf("ending program\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and ,

**OUTPUT**

```
Starting program
now listening on tcp!
ending program
```

but server socket is not actually listening...

expected output:

```
Starting program
now listening on tcp!
read...
write...
read...
write...
read...
write..
```

I can't figure our what I am missing, I know I didn't implemented read, write yet but I will do it after when server socket seems to working fine and listening properly.

**NOTE**: I am doing this in linux (specifically ubuntu)

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Just what do you think `((struct sockaddr_in *)result->ai_addr)->sin_port = htons(5678);` actually does?  You're casting the `ai_addr` element returned from `getaddrinfo()` to a `struct sockaddr_in`, trying to modify it?!?!?

Comment: The `result` variable is filled by the function `getaddrinfo`. The variable is allocated by you and you can modify it if you like. But the pointers in that variable points to locations you don't own. You should not try to modify it. Copy to `addrin` and update the port number in you own data.

Comment: I appreciate your responses guys.. but after scratching my head I took a break and read the code track the code again so, I found that I forgot the error handling of  "accept"... yeah, stupid me... but after that I found that accept was returning error due to fcntl... after removing it is working fine...

Comment: so can anyone suggest me what should I do.. as I ressolved it so should I delete this question or post my solution?

Comment: If you want to assign port numbers to the list that `getaddrinfo()` returns, then you should be passing the port number to `getaddrinfo()` in its 2nd parameter, ie: `getaddrinfo(host, "5678", &hints, &result)`. It will then parse and copy that value into the resulting `sockaddr`s for you.

Answer (score 1):

Calling getaddrinfo to initialize a local list socket seems like overkill.

Start with this.  This is a simple "create a listen socket and wait for an incoming TCP connection" code sample.

```
int tcp_socket_listen(int listen_connection)
{
     struct sockaddr_in addr = {0};
     sockaddr_in addrRemote = {0};
     socklen_t sizeRemote = 0;
     int tcp_socket = -1;

     s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     _check(s, "socket");

     addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     addr.sin_port = htons(5678);
     _check(bind(s, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)), "bind");

     _check(listen(sock, listen_connection), "listen");

     sizeRemote = sizeof(addrRemote);
     tcp_sock = accept(s, (sockaddr*)&addrRemote, &sizeRemote);

     _check(tcp_sock, "accept");

     printf("now listening on TCP\n");

     return tcp_sock;
}
```

Now if you want to bind to a specific adapter (e.g. "enp0s3") instead of the default ("all adapters") or need IPV6 support, you can peruse my sample code on github [here](https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver/blob/d2d06a6d002d1e2fba312cf4993b08bb57a0346b/networkutils/adapters.cpp#L111) for the `GetSocketAddressForAdapter` and use that address for the `bind` call instead of the default `addr` address above.  It's C++, but you can probably port it to straight C with a little work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it but I want to do specifically in this way because I have other stuff too which can be handled easily in this way... and yeah I ressolved it so please check my comment.. what was the error.